# How do I get IntelliSense for referenced .NET assembly without a project or any other supplemental file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intellisense, fiddler

#### I'm looking for a way to utilize IntelliSense in a stand-alone code file.

### Use Case

Fiddler 4 comes with a C# source file (`{MyDocuments}\Fiddler2\Scripts\CustomRules.cs`) for writing custom traffic routing rules.

That file is suggested to be edited using either Fiddler's ScriptEditor, Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code.

Opening the file in any of these editors doesn't provide code completion for the provided event handlers' parameters. That's because IntelliSense doesn't know where to take the objects' information from.

It's hard to program against Fiddler's custom objects if I don't know these objects' properties or methods. So, I wonder how to enable IntelliSense for that file.

The file begins with a reference to a `Fiddler` assembly:

```
using System;
using Fiddler;
...
```

Since the `Fiddler.dll` assembly is not in the GAC, IntelliSense is unable to retrieve the corresponding objects' information.

### Assumption

From JavaScript I know there is a `reference` comment tag available that enables IntelliSense to find missing type information by providing it a path to a JavaScript file containing the missing type definition:

```js
/// <reference path="Utilities.js" />
```

Is there something similar available for .NET?

I would be looking for something like:

```cs
using System;
using Fiddler; /// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Telerik\Fiddler\Fiddler.dll" />
```

Comment: Usually you don’t need to do anything and it doesn’t matter if an assembly is in the GAC or not. Intellisense (at least in Visual Studio – I don’t know about VS Code) should automatically show all objects from the DLL. What happens if you enter `Fiddler.` to restrict Intellisense to show everything from this namespace? It should show you all classes from this namespace. If you have a Fiddler object, Intellisense should also automatically show you all public members of this object.

Comment: Use a tool like ILSpy to analyze Fiddler.dll and its API should be quite clear to you. Telerik also has online documentation, https://docs.telerik.com/fiddlercore/api/fiddler

Comment: @ckuri: If the DLL isn't somewhere in the path or in the GAC, neither VS Code nor VS will show anything without a project file or something else giving a hint on there the dll can be found. Just ask yourself: Do you know where `Any.dll` is? So, who could you possibly tell anything about that dll?

Comment: @LexLi: That is not the question here. The question is: How do I get IntelliSense for ___any___ referenced .NET assembly without a project or any other supplemental file?

Comment: @AxD Visual Studio would know where Any.dll is, because you would have added it to your project references – or at least you should have. If you didn’t, the line `using Fiddler;` would be marked as an error (and you haven’t mentioned that it gives you an error), because Visual Studio wouldn’t know of this namespace. If it does know of this namespace it has found a DLL containing the namespace, type and member metadata.

Comment: @ckuri: You read the title of my question, didn't you? It ___explicitly___ reads: "_without a project or any other supplemental file_". Please read my question. Everything else I already know. This is not a beginner's question. I'm looking for advanced/expert knowledge.

Comment: Is there any documentation regarding how fiddler consumes the `CustomRules.cs` file so that you can perhaps create a project with similar build setup to Fiddler so that you get intellisense? I'm afraid what you're asking is otherwise not possible using Visual Studio unless you use .csx which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something similar available for .NET?

**In fact**, there is no such way, tool to get the Intellisense of a .Net assembly without  instantiating its object or using its namespace directly.

`.NET assmebly` is different from Javascript front-end files and has **a tight encapsulation**, so if your wishes can be achieved, this is a serious violation of **.Net rules**.

It is for this reason that in **.Net**, there is no way to obtain Intellisense similar to Javascript.

And to obtain the Intellisense of the .Net assembly, it is actually referring to the dll.

Here, it is impossible to get rid of referencing `Fiddler.dll` by project or instantiating its object and extract the Intellisense among them. This is also a security consideration for the .net project.

So the best **solution** to obtain the intellisense of .Net assembly is that:

**1)** Right-click on your project-->`Add Reference` to this `Fiddler.dll`

**2)** using its namespace in code editor.

Comment: I see. Thank you, @Perry, for enlightening me. I filed a feature request at Fiddler now: https://feedback.telerik.com/fiddler/1463205-publish-public-interfaces-fiddler-dll-for-intellisense

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a reference to Fiddler.exe.

[image: Fiddler.exe reference]

Edit: I see now that you want a general solution for all use cases. I only answered how you can get Intellisense working for your particular example. I'll delete this answer if it doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you, @Mika, for trying to help. I apprehend now. Please leave your answer in here as it might be helpful to others.